# Tkinter How To Make Button In Middle of Window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make two buttons that are in the middle of the page - meaning one on top of the other with the same x-coordinates but the y-coordinates would have to be just outside the centre so that it would look proportionally correct

**Code:** [ This is what I have got so far ]

```
from tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.signup_button = Button(master, text="Sign Up", width=6,height=2)
        self.login_button = Button(master, text="Login", width=6,height=2)

        self.signup_button.grid()
        self.login_button.grid()

root=Tk()
run=Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Also, How do they position everything in such an organised manner**:

[image: HOW DO THEY POSITION EVERYTHING SO WELL?!]

Comment: They use a precise method i.e. `widget.place(x,y)`. If you want the buttons to be in the middle `place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)`. If you want it be in the middle x axis `place(relx=0.5,y=y,anchor=CENTER)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what exactly do you expect as result, but you can try to adjust padx and pady values:

```
self.signup_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx=5, pady=5)
self.login_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx=5, pady=5)
```